# How can I apply BandPass filter to EEG data being plotted in Processing 3?

Tags: processing, signal-processing, bandpass-filter

I am trying to apply a 4-35Hz BandPass filter in processing. I explored the Sound library but I think it is strictly limited to audio files.

**Is there any library for fast implementation of signal filtering in Processing?** I found this-- https://github.com/berndporr/iirj -- but since this is an external library for Java -- importing steps are not very clear.
Please share your insights.

Appreciate your time. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm surprised the Sound library doesn't expose the data arrays easily.

I recommend using the [Minim library](http://code.compartmental.net/tools/minim/) in Processing. It should be simpler and come with plenty of examples. What you're after is [Minim's BandPass filter](http://code.compartmental.net/minim/javadoc/ddf/minim/effects/BandPass.html) and there's already a [BandPass example](https://github.com/ddf/Minim/tree/master/examples/Synthesis/BandPassFilter).

You can access it via **Processing > Examples > Contributed Libraries > Minim > Synthesis > BandPassFilter** once you install the library (if it's not already there).

The demo is audio focus, but you should be able to pass a float[] signal to one of the available UGens and pass that to the BandPass filter.

Regarding the IIRJ library, as you can see in the readme, there's a link to the [MavenCentral repo](https://search.maven.org/artifact/uk.me.berndporr/iirj/1.1/jar) where you can download [the compiled jar library](https://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=uk/me/berndporr/iirj/1.1/iirj-1.1.jar)

Drag and drop that .jar file into your Processing Java sketch and you should be able to test importing the library:

```
import uk.me.berndporr.iirj.*;
Butterworth butterworth = new Butterworth();
```

Next up you'll need to download an unzip the [javadocs](https://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=uk/me/berndporr/iirj/1.1/iirj-1.1-javadoc.jar) and see how this library expects the 1D signal coming in

Comment: Hey, thank you ! This is great, I think I will be able to implement at least one of the two solutions you provided. Appreciate your detailed insights. :)